# Getting Session Variable from within AppKernel.php in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Fairly new to PHP and Symfony: How do I gain access various session variable from within an include file that is included in AppKernel.php?  I'm using Symfony 2.8. I've successfully tested the following, but it's not officially approved. I'd prefer to use Symfony objects to access the session.

```
session_start();
if (isset($session['userid'])) {
    $userid = $_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['userid'];
}
```

I tried getting the session from the Symfony Request object using the following, but it looks like "Request::createFromGlobals" is creating another Request object vs. creating a Request object from an existing Request object.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require_once '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php';

...

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$session = $request->get('session');
```

The $session variable returns null.

Comment: Could you please tell mewhich documentation involves such notions? I am trying to understand how, from inside AppKernel.php, such things can happen (Of course I tried first to help but found this a bit confusing)

Comment: hmmm... not sure that documentation exists. Technically, I've just added an include line to AppKernel.php, in the form of  `include foo.php';` So the heavy lifting is happening in foo.php.

Comment: If you're referring to the first option not being approved, there's this. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html "Symfony sessions are designed to replace several native PHP functions. Applications should avoid using session_start(), session_regenerate_id(), session_id(), session_name(), and session_destroy() and instead use the APIs in the following section."

Comment: I agree with you, it is just that I am used to dealing with Request and Session objects inside bundles/controllers, not inside appKernel.php (which I thought the role is to register the bundles or generally redefine Kernel methods )

Comment: about your second comment, yes Symfony brings a lot of benefits regarding sessions than raw PHP

Comment: yes when you use `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
$session = new Session();
$session->start();` your $session object is not NULL

Comment: If you would like session information outside of a controller, an event listener on a kernel event is probably a better choice. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html

Answer (score 1):

You can gain access to session variables in event listeners. Here is an example of a listener for the kernel.request event:

```
services:
    app.security:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\Security
        arguments: [@session]
        tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: checkAccess }
```

And part of the AppBundle\EventListener\Security class:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class Security
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * The constructor.
     *
     * @param Session         $session
     */
    public function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function checkAccess(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        // Do what you like...
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if injecting the session will work as desired here since the listener will be constructed very early in the request processing.  $event->getRequest()->getSession() might be a better approach.